# How to find Amplitude of a Signal in Simulink

Tags: signal, processing

I have a com port object sampling at 0.01 seconds a stream of data. The 'data' is a signal from an accelerometer with a sinusoidal shape.

I need to do math operations on the amplitude of this signal.

What is the best way to find the amplitude of a signal in Simulink?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the signal has a constant amplitud, add matlab function block and find the higher value by comparing.

More info about matlab function block [here](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/incorporating-matlab-algorithms-into-a-simulink-model-69028.html)

Good luck!